# Pandas - check if dataframe columns contain key:value pairs from a dictionary

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary, string-matching

This question is related to another question I had posted. 
[Pandas - check if a string column in one dataframe contains a pair of strings from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443280/pandas-check-if-a-string-column-in-one-dataframe-contains-a-pair-of-strings-fr/43444266#43444266)

My goal is to check if two different columns of a dataframe contain a pair of string values and if the condition is met, then extract one of the values.

I have two dataframes like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'consumption':['squirrelate apple', 'monkey likesapple', 
                                  'monkey banana gets', 'badger/getsbanana', 'giraffe eats grass', 'badger apple.loves', 'elephant is huge', 'elephant/eats/', 'squirrel.digsingrass'], 
                    'name': ['apple', 'appleisred', 'banana is tropical', 'banana is soft', 'lemon is sour', 'washington apples', 'kiwi', 'bananas', 'apples']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'food':['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana'], 'creature':['squirrel', 'badger', 'monkey', 'elephant']})

In [187]:df1
Out[187]: 
            consumption                name
0     squirrelate apple               apple
1     monkey likesapple          appleisred
2    monkey banana gets  banana is tropical
3     badger/getsbanana      banana is soft
4    giraffe eats grass       lemon is sour
5    badger apple.loves   washington apples
6      elephant is huge                kiwi
7        elephant/eats/             bananas
8  squirrel.digsingrass              apples

In[188]: df2
Out[188]: 
   creature    food
0  squirrel   apple
1    badger   apple
2    monkey  banana
3  elephant  banana
```

What I want to do is test if 'apple' occurs in `df1['name']` and 'squirrel' occurs in `df1['consumption']` and if both conditions are met then extract 'squirrel' from `df1['consumption']` into a new column `df['creature']`. The result should look like:

```
Out[189]: 
            consumption  creature                name
0     squirrelate apple  squirrel               apple
1     monkey likesapple       NaN          appleisred
2    monkey banana gets    monkey  banana is tropical
3     badger/getsbanana       NaN      banana is soft
4    giraffe eats grass       NaN       lemon is sour
5    badger apple.loves    badger   washington apples
6      elephant is huge       NaN                kiwi
7        elephant/eats/  elephant             bananas
8  squirrel.digsingrass       NaN              apples
```

If there was no paired value constraint, I could have done something simple like :

```
np.where((df1['consumption'].str.contains(<creature_string>, case = False)) & (df1['name'].str.contains(<food_string>, case = False)), df['consumption'].str.extract(<creature_string>), np.nan)
```

but I must check for pairs so I tried to make a dictionary of food as keys and creatures as values , then make a string var of all the creatures for a given food key and look for those using str.contains :

```
unique_food = df2.food.unique()
food_dict = {elem : pd.DataFrame for elem in unique_food}
for key in food_dict.keys():
    food_dict[key] = df2[:][df2.food == key]

# create key:value pairs of food key and creature strings
food_strings = {}
for key, values in food_dict.items():
    food_strings.update({key: '|'.join(map(str, list(food_dict[key]['creature'].unique())))})

In[199]: food_strings
Out[199]: {'apple': 'squirrel|badger', 'banana': 'monkey|elephant'}
```

The problem is when I try to now apply str.contains:

```
for key, value in food_strings.items():
    np.where((df1['name'].str.contains('('+food_strings[key]+')', case = False)) & 
             (df1['consumption'].str.contains('('+food_strings[value]+')', case = False)), df1['consumptions'].str.extract('('+food_strings[value]+')'), np.nan)
```

I get a `KeyError:` .

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-7ab718066040> in <module>()
      1 for key, value in food_strings.items():
      2     np.where((df1['name'].str.contains('('+food_strings[key]+')', case = False)) & 
----> 3              (df1['consumption'].str.contains('('+food_strings[value]+')', case = False)), df1['consumption'].str.extract('('+food_strings[value]+')'), np.nan)

KeyError: 'squirrel|badger'
```

When I just try for only the value and not the key, it works for the first key:value pair but not the second:

```
for key in food_strings.keys():
    df1['test'] = np.where(df1['consumption'].str.contains('('+food_strings[key]+')', case =False), 
                                df1['consumption'].str.extract('('+food_strings[key]+')', expand=False), 
                                np.nan)

df1
Out[196]: 
            consumption                name      test
0     squirrelate apple               apple  squirrel
1     monkey likesapple          appleisred       NaN
2    monkey banana gets  banana is tropical       NaN
3     badger/getsbanana      banana is soft    badger
4    giraffe eats grass       lemon is sour       NaN
5    badger apple.loves   washington apples    badger
6      elephant is huge                kiwi       NaN
7        elephant/eats/             bananas       NaN
8  squirrel.digsingrass              apples  squirrel
```

I got the ones matching apple and squirrel|badger but missed banana:monkey|elephant.

can someone please help?

Comment: I think, each values of `food_dict` contains dataframe instead of string. The error occurs when you loop in `for key, value in food_dict.items():`. You give `value` as a dataframe to `food_strings[value]`.

Comment: @titipat That's typos sorry - but good catch. I edited the question and pasted the exact error i get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d1 = df1.dropna()
d2 = df2.dropna()

sump = d1.consumption.values.tolist()
name = d1.name.values.tolist()
cret = d2.creature.values.tolist() 
food = d2.food.values.tolist()

check = np.array(
    [
        [c in s and f in n for c, f in zip(cret, food)]
        for s, n in zip(sump, name)
    ]
)

# create a new series with the index of `d1` where we dropped na
# then reindex with `df1.index` prior to `assign`
test = pd.Series(check.dot(d2[['creature']].values).ravel(), d1.index)
test = test.reindex(df1.index, fill_value='')
df1.assign(test=test)

            consumption                name      test
0     squirrelate apple               apple  squirrel
1     monkey likesapple          appleisred          
2    monkey banana gets  banana is tropical    monkey
3     badger/getsbanana      banana is soft          
4    giraffe eats grass       lemon is sour          
5    badger apple.loves   washington apples    badger
6      elephant is huge                kiwi          
7        elephant/eats/             bananas  elephant
8  squirrel.digsingrass              apples  squirrel
```

Comment: hi ! thanks - awesome solution. One problem - when the lists contains None values, it breaks. I get this error : `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`. I made a list without Nonetypes, `sump = df1[df1.consumption.notnull()]['consumption'].values.tolist()` for sump, name, cret and food. Then the `check` function works but in df1.assign , I get : `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: When iterating through zip(sump, name), i have to somehow get a NaN / None value when either of c - s are nonetype or f - n are nonetype.

Comment: dropna wouldn't work . . . i would be altering the dataframe then !

Comment: as an update: when I do: `test = test.reindex(df1.index, fill_value='')`  `df1.assign(test=test)` , the reindexing creates multiple matches - for e.g.: squirrelsquirrelsquirrelsquirrel . I did this instead: `test = pd.DataFrame(check.dot(d2[['creature']].values).ravel(), d1.index, columns=['some_var'])` and then performed an index merge: `d1 = d1.merge(test, how='left', left_index = True, right_index = True)` - does that make sense?

Comment: The merge makes sense... However, `join` "merges" on index by default and might be better.... However/However, you shouldn't be getting multiple matches on the reindex unless you had a non-unique index in `df1` in the first place.  As you have represented your data, you did not.

Comment: btw - this function is really good ! changed the whole program

Comment: hi ! is there a way to control not finding second matches? For e.g.: If Squirrel and Apple has been found, don't look for rest of the matches? I have double matching sometimes because the conditions are being met twice - i want to create a rule whereby when condition is met for the first time - don't look for a match in that row again. . .